# Python: Process file using multiple cores

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am currently trying to read a large file (80 million lines), where I need to make a computationally intensive matrix multiplication for each entry. After calculating this, I want to insert the result into a database. Because of the time intensive manner of this process, I want to split the file onto multiple cores to speed up the process.

After researching I found this promising attempt, which split a file into *n* parts.

```
def file_block(fp, number_of_blocks, block):
    '''
    A generator that splits a file into blocks and iterates
    over the lines of one of the blocks.

    '''

    assert 0 <= block and block < number_of_blocks
    assert 0 < number_of_blocks

    fp.seek(0,2)
    file_size = fp.tell()

    ini = file_size * block / number_of_blocks
    end = file_size * (1 + block) / number_of_blocks

    if ini <= 0:
        fp.seek(0)
    else:
        fp.seek(ini-1)
        fp.readline()

    while fp.tell() < end:
        yield fp.readline()
```

Iteratively, you can call the function like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fp = open(filename)
    number_of_chunks = 4
    for chunk_number in range(number_of_chunks):
        print chunk_number, 100 * '='
        for line in file_block(fp, number_of_chunks, chunk_number):
            process(line)
```

While this works, I run into problems, parallelizing this using multiprocessing:

```
fp = open(filename)
number_of_chunks = 4
li = [file_block(fp, number_of_chunks, chunk_number) for chunk_number in range(number_of_chunks)]

p = Pool(cpu_count() - 1)
p.map(processChunk,li)
```

With the error being, that generators cannot be pickled.

While I understand this error, it is too expensive to first iterate over the whole file to put all lines into a list.

Moreover, I want to use blocks of lines per core per iteration, because it is more efficient to insert multiple lines into the database at once (instead of 1 by 1 if using the typical map approach)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could do an initial pass of the large file to make a note of seek co-ordinates and the number of lines to read from that position. You can then call your multiprocessing with these two numbers and keep the generator tucked away in each process

Comment: Is it possible to split the file into four files first?

Comment: Move the file opening and `file_block` code into each thread instead of trying to initialize it before the thread starts. It won't be a problem having the file open 4 times instead of just once, as long as it's read only.

Comment: You might be better off using a package that can handle the reading of large files that are out of memory such as Blaze

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating generators up front and passing them into each thread, leave that to the thread code.

```
def processChunk(params):
    filename, chunk_number, number_of_chunks = params
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        for line in file_block(fp, number_of_chunks, chunk_number):
            process(line)

li = [(filename, i, number_of_chunks) for i in range(number_of_chunks)]
p.map(processChunk, li)
```